# LDAP: Query syntax

Tags: active-directory, ldap, querying

I've basically forgotten everything I ever learned about querying AD, and now I have a need to retrieve the list of users in one particular dept (DAAS). I've determined that there is an Organizational Unit called DAAS. I just can't figure out how to limit the list to that OU.

This string works, but retrieves the entire organization;

```
strQueryDL = "<LDAP://" & strDefaultNamingContext & ">;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user));distinguishedName;subtree"
```

This string doesn't work;

```
strQueryDL = "<LDAP://" & strDefaultNamingContext & ">;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(OU=DAAS));distinguishedName;subtree"
```

This string doesn't work, either;

```
strQueryDL = "<LDAP://OU=DAAS" & strDefaultNamingContext & ">;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user));distinguishedName;subtree"
```

Where does that darn OU belong in this string?

Thanks!
DC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entries don't have to contain the OU attribute just because it's somewhere in their DN.  They only are required to have their RDN value in them.  If this makes no sense, see below<\a>.

You can find out the DN of all of the subtrees whose dn starts with ou=daas with

```
strQueryDL = "<LDAP://" & strDefaultNamingContext & ">;(&(objectCategory=organizationalunit)(OU=DAAS));distinguishedName;subtree"
```

Once you have that, you can use that DN where you have strDefaultNamingContext.

There's also a extensible search form that can specify a search is to be performed against the DN rather than the attributes, but I don't know if it works in AD. If it does work in AD, that form would be:

```
strQueryDL = "<LDAP://" & strDefaultNamingContext & ">;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(OU:dn:=DAAS));distinguishedName;subtree"
```

A DN  is made up of a bunch of DN components. Each component is an attribute value pair, joined with an `=`. You can join components at the same level with a `+`, but usually you just chain them with `,`. Components at the same level are unordered. The bit from the start of the DN to the `,` is the RDN, and must be represented on the entry. Everything else in the DN is the superior DN. If the entry is not the top level entry in its tree, the superior DN must be represented by its own entry, but none of those values need to be on the subordinate entries.

Exactly what all that means is another question, and it has been asked before, multiple times, and I'm looking through the different ones to find out which has the best answer... or whether I should submit an answer.  Once I finish that search, I'll replace this text with a link.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand the first sentence (it's been too long), but the search string you gave me worked. It actually gave me 8 results, so I had to figure out which one to use, but I got there. The surprise was that there is a Users OU under DAAS, but there is also a DAAS OU under Users. A script I found elsewhere showed me that.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with the last one, but were probably just missing a comma after the OU (if the OU is at the root of the domain).

But if you already know the `distinguishedName` of the OU, then you can just use that directly. The point is, the string should end up looking something like this (assuming the DN of the OU is at `domain.com/DAAS`):

```
strQueryDL = "<LDAP://OU=DAAS,DC=domain,DC=com>;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user));distinguishedName;subtree"
```

Ed Grimm's answer shows you how to find the OU itself, which will help you get the DN of the OU if you don't already know it.

Comment: Thanks! You were right, of course, about the missing comma, but just correcting that wasn't enough. I was missing the necessary information to build the search string. Ed Grimm's answer addressed that. So, I was able to get past this hurdle.